# JavaScript calculator NaN

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple calculator on html and javascript, but when I enter 2 numbers, the result is just NaN.
I am using google chrome.
I now think that it may be a problem with my HTML code.
I am only just strting to use HTML and JavaScript, so word answers simply please.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function workOut()  {
var num1 = (document.getElementById('num1').value)
var num2 = (document.getElementById('num2').value)

if(document.getElementById('operation').value=="plus") 
{
    var answer= Number(num1) + Number(num2);
    alert(answer);
}
if(document.getElementById('operation').value=="minus") 
{
    var answer= num1 - num2;
    alert(answer);
}
if(document.getElementById('operation').value=="multiply") 
{
    var answer= num1 * num2;
    alert(answer);
}
if(document.getElementById('operation').value=="divide") 
{
    var answer= num1 / num2;
    alert(answer);
}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Calculator</h1>

<form name="calculatordata">
<table width="50%" border="1px dashed">
<tr>
        <td id="num1">Number 1</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="number1" /></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <select id="operation">
        <option value="plus">+</option>
        <option value="minus">-</option>
        <option value="multiply">x</option>
        <option value="divide">/</option>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td id="num2">Number 2</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="number2" /></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onClick="return          workOut();"/></td>
        <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: var num1 = Number((document.getElementById('num1').value));
var num2 = Number((document.getElementById('num2').value));. try this. You are only parsing numbers in case of addition

Comment: Can you post a complete code example, including your HTML?

Comment: because .value returns a string and not a number..

Comment: @LuckySoni "5" + "5" = "55" not NaN...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you have given 'num1', 'num2' and 'operation' as **name** for the input elements and not **id**? Remember you are using **getElementById**. The below html makes your function work fine.

```
<form name='test'>
<input type='text' name='num1' id='num1'/>
<input type='text' name='num2' id='num2'/>
<input type='text' name='operation' id='operation'/>
<input type='button' value='Calc' onclick='workOut()'/>
</form>
```

Also, you can safely use parseFloat in many cases in JS. All number variables are float in JS anyway. There is no differenciation of int and float.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `parseInt(num1)` function,

```
var answer= parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
```

Comment: What if the number is 0.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I can almost guarantee you that one of the `inputs` is returning an undefined value only because of what is alerted. Let's test these cases ( let us assumed you entered two 5s):

- "5" + "5" = "55"
- null + "5" = "null5"
- undefined + "5" = NaN

Therefore, one of the numbers you're adding together is `undefined`